# Can Cordova Plugman be used to install plugins into IBM Worklight projects?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

Wondering if it's possible to install Cordova plugins into an IBM Worklight project, and if it is, if someone could share an example of the correct plugman syntax?

Also are there any gotchas about the version of Cordova bundled?  Does one need to reopen the project after or is a refresh sufficient?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I assume it's possible. From the docs it looks like you could do something like this: `plugman install --platform ios --project [path-to-ios-native-folder-under-iphone-environment] --plugin <name|url|path> --www <directory>`. I would be interested in your results if you care to share.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to read about Cordova support in Worklight: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova

- A Worklight project is not a Cordova project
- A plug-in is:

  - added by referencing it in config.xml
  - For iOS, the implementation files must be added in Xcode; placing them in the Worklight project in Eclipse and building it will not make the plug-in part of the generated Xcode project (to be later built in Xcode...)
  - For Android and Windows Phone, the implementation files can be placed in Eclipse
  - I believe the support for BlackBerry 10 in this category is minimal. Not sure